# How to set custom error message IsEnum of class-validator in nestjs

Tags: typescript, enums, class-validator

I'm using nestjs and I'm using the `@IsEnum(Enum)` keyword.

If the values ​​that can be entered into the enum are `A, B, C`, and if `B1` is entered, an error occurs.

```js
response: {
    statusCode: 400,
    message: [ 'each value in tag must be a valid enum value' ],
    error: 'Bad Request'
  },
  status: 400
```

It simply displays the above log. I want to know what value is wrong.

If I entered `A,B1,C`, I would like to receive an error message saying 'The value of B1 is incorrect'.

```js
@IsEnum(EnumName, { each: true })
  enumValues: EnumName[] = [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  import { difference } from 'lodash';

  @IsEnum(EnumName, {
    message: (args: ValidationArguments) => {
      const { value, constraints } = args;
      const correctValues = Object.values(constraints[0]);
      const incorrectValues = difference(value, correctValues);
      return `The values of ${incorrectValues} are incorrect`;
    },
    each: true,
  })
```